# how do i make it so that when a button is pressed, this variable decreases by one? (Roblox studio, .Lua)

Tags: lua, roblox

what i want to do is when a button is pressed (in Startergui.ExitGUI.ExitBtn) it decreases a variable value (for me it is "seatsOccupied") by 1. I want to also make it so that if seatsOccupied = 0 then it changes the playercount.text and countdown.text to: playercount.text = "0 / 10" and countdown.text = "Waiting for players.." but i know how to do that.
main script:

```
seatsOccupied = 0
textLabel = game.Workspace.TruckLanes.InvisibleSurfaceGui.BillboardGui.Frame.TextLabel
playercount = game.Workspace.TruckLanes.InvisibleSurfaceGui.BillboardGui.Frame.Countdown
countdown = 15
signtext = game.Workspace.TruckLanes.Lane2.Sign.Top.SurfaceGui.TextLabel
local TeleportService = game:GetService("TeleportService")
truckSeats = script.Parent.Parent.Truck.Seats:GetChildren() -- define truckSeats here

playercount.Text = "Players: 0 / 10"

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)

    if player then
        for i, seat in pairs(truckSeats) do -- use the truckSeats variable here
            if not seat.Occupant then
                seat:Sit(player.Character.Humanoid)
                seatsOccupied = seatsOccupied + 1
                playercount.Text = "Players: " .. seatsOccupied .. "/" .. #truckSeats
                player.Character.Humanoid.JumpPower = 0
                game.ReplicatedStorage.ShowExitGUI:FireClient(player)

                for i = 15,0 -1 do
                    game.Workspace.TruckLanes.InvisibleSurfaceGui.BillboardGui.TextLabel.Text = "Leaving in " ..i.." seconds"
                end
                for i = 15, 0, -1 do
                    textLabel.Text = "Leaving in " .. i .. " seconds"
                    signtext.Text = "Leaving in " .. i .. " seconds"
                    wait(1)
                end


                -- Move truck
                -- Reserve server

                local players = {}

                for i, v in pairs(game.Workspace.TruckLanes.Lane2.Truck.Seats:GetChildren()) do
                    if v.Occupant then
                        print("Occupant found. " .. v.Parent.Name)
                        table.insert(players, game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(v.Occupant.Parent))
                    end
                end

                if #players > 0 then

                    for i = 0, 150, 1 do -- Change 30 to number of studs
                        script.Parent.Parent.Truck:TranslateBy(script.Parent.Parent.Truck.Hitbox.CFrame.lookVector)
                        wait(0.01)
                    end
                    for i = 0, 150, 1 do -- Change 30 to number of studs
                        script.Parent.Parent.Truck:TranslateBy(-script.Parent.Parent.Truck.Hitbox.CFrame.lookVector)
                        wait(0.01)
                    end

                    local serverData = TeleportService:ReserveServer(12433394609)

                    TeleportService:TeleportToPrivateServer(12433394609, serverData, players)
                    for i = 0, 150, 1 do -- Change 30 to number of studs
                        script.Parent.Parent.Truck:TranslateBy(-script.Parent.Parent.Truck.Hitbox.CFrame.lookVector)
                        wait(0.01)
                    end
                    textLabel.Text = "Waiting For Players.."
                    playercount.Text = "0 / 10"
                end
            end
        end
    end
end)
-- WHERE I DO NOT KNOW WHAT TO DO/WHY ITS NOT WORKING
button = game.StarterGui.ExitGUI.ExitBtn.MouseButton1Click

local function onExitButtonClicked()
    if seatsOccupied > 0 then
        seatsOccupied = seatsOccupied - 1
        playercount.Text = "Players: " .. seatsOccupied .. "/" .. #truckSeats
        if seatsOccupied == 0 then
            textLabel.Text = "Waiting For Players.."
            playercount.Text = "0 / " .. #truckSeats
        end
    end
end

button:Connect(onExitButtonClicked)
```

Second script (localscript) that tells the button to do stuff

```
local clicked = game.ReplicatedStorage.LeaveTruck:FireServer()

-- Connect the function to the ShowExitGUI event
game.ReplicatedStorage.ShowExitGUI.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.ExitBtn.Visible = true
end)

ExitButtonClicked = function()
    print("Exit button clicked")
    game.ReplicatedStorage.LeaveTruck:FireServer()
    script.Parent.ExitBtn.Visible = false
    print("its trueeeeeee")
end

-- Connect the function to the ExitBtn's MouseButton1Click event
script.Parent.ExitBtn.MouseButton1Click:Connect(ExitButtonClicked)
```

Hierarchy:                                                                                                 First script:                                                                                           game -> workspace -> trucklanes -> lane2 -> lane2detector -> detectorscript                               Second script:                                                                                            game -> starterGui -> exitgui -> ClientExit (Aka the script)                                             the button:                                                                                           game -> startergui -> exitgui -> ExitBtn (aka the button)

I tried the above scripts, but they don't work. I was expecting to:                                        contact with the border                                                                                   seat the player                                                                                         countdown from 15 seconds and a player count                                                                 -- where it doesn't work                                                                                       when the player presses the leave/exitbtn, it decreases the seatsoccupied value by 1, and when the value is 0, it changes the playercount.text and countdown.text to: "0/10" and "Waiting for players.."

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your if statements doesn't allow for the case where `seatsOccupied` is ever equal to zero. And that is because the `seatsOccupied == 0` case is inside the first if-statement.

```lua
local function onExitButtonClicked()
    if seatsOccupied > 0 then
        ...
        if seatsOccupied == 0 then
            ...
        end
    end
end
```

You need to move this case to be on the same level as the first.

```lua
local function onExitButtonClicked()
    if seatsOccupied > 0 then
        ...
    else if seatsOccupied == 0 then
        ...
    end
end
```

Comment: Technically, you don't even need the `if seatsOccupied == 0`, a simple else is good enough.